# Test void method behavior junit and mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Given this service I'd like to test that the role property of stuff object is properly set:

```
public void saveAStuffForAnEvent(Event whatever) {
    if (whatever == null){
        Stuff stuff = StuffBuilder().role(StuffRoles.DEFAULT).build();
        stuffRepository.save(stuff);
    } else {
        Stuff stuff = StuffBuilder().role(StuffRoles.OTHER).build();
        stuffRepository.save(stuff);
    }
}
```

How can I test that stuff object is properly created with the DEFAULT role?

Comment: No, what you want to test is that the correct data is saved, because that's what the method does. So you should verify that in the database. For example with `stuffRepository.findAll()` and the suitable assertions afterwards (if you have a test database).

Comment: Or inject a mock `stuffRepository` and ensure that the object passed to it meets the requirements.

Comment: Mock `stuffRepository` and use `ArgumentCaptor` to check `stuffRepository.save` is called with the correct object.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62080899/how-do-i-write-unit-test-for-function-with-void-return-type/62081019#62081019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use captor.

In your test create field with @Captor annotation like:

```
@Mock
private StuffRepository stuffRepository;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Stuff> stuffCaptor;
```

Then in test after:

```
// when
subject.saveAStuffForAnEvent(event);
// then
verify(stuffRepository).save(stuffCaptor.capture());
assertThat(stuffCaptor.getValue().getRole()).isEqualTo(StuffRoles.DEFAULT);
```

Or if it's integration test then:

```
// when
subject.saveAStuffForAnEvent(event);
//then
assertThat(subject.findAll().get(0).getRole()).isEqualTo(StuffRoles.DEFAULT);
```